# mysql 1290: have set "secure_file_priv" and used absolute path

Tags: mysql

#### System: Centos

#### Vesion:

`Server version: 5.5.56-log Source distribution`

#### What I did:

Have set the `secure_file_priv` in my `/etc/my.cnf`

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+---------------+
| Variable_name    | Value         |
+------------------+---------------+
| secure_file_priv | /target_file  |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Have restarted myssql service by `service mysql restart`, and inaddition I have restart the server/machine too

and I set `chmod 777 /target_file`

But I still get

```
>> select * from mytable  into outfile '/target_file/config';
>> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Did I miss something?